# Create files from C++ code running by Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I have `C++` code that create files in local `FS`, and I want to run this code in JS using `Emscripten`.
My question is if it possible to create and save files from code that run by the browser on my local FS?
Is there any necessary changes I should make?

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate to the one linked.  This question asks about SAVING files, the other question asks about READING files.  As the other answer indicates, reading is possible as long as you indicate the file at compile time to load into the virtual file system.  Saving is more tricky, and (I expect) would require JS to create a file image that the user has to manually agree to download.

Comment: `FS.readFile()` and Data URL would be useful

Comment: any example if possible? :) @zakki

Comment: @CharlesOfria - tnx for that, I really didn't understand how this Q is link to the duplicate

Comment: Someting like this.  https://gist.github.com/zakki/b43609a219d9eed5477d87ca99ff3728

Comment: Im not sure I understand. if I have c++ code like: `FILE *f; f=fopen("c:\","wb");  `how the JS code you shared gonna help? @zakki

Comment: JavaScript in web browsers can't access local fs, so write to memfs and download it via <a href="data:...">

Comment: sorry, still not sure I got it.. but the JS code generate automaticly, how do I add this code to JS file? @zakki

Comment: `EM_ASM*` in c or just `<script>` tag in html.